# What are the different ways to show images in a Spring project? Not able to show static images

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jsp

I've tried a lot of things but the only thing which is able to show images is using  the following code:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/imagesresources/**"
    location="/resources/images/" />
```

Take the following code as an example

```
<body background="../../resources/images/contactus.jpg">
<h2>Contact Us</h2> </body>
```

In eclipse if I do ctrl+click the body tag, contactus.jpg is being shown by opening in the next tab. But when I start tomcat there is no image and when I go to console bu F12 it says the following

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Also, the url is being shown for the image as:

```
http://localhost:8080/resources/images/contactus.jpg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the URL as

```
<body background="imagesresources/contactus.jpg">
```

Your mapping for resources is defined as

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/imagesresources/**"
    location="/resources/images/" />
```

Spring mvc configures all resources to be accessible through your defined mapping i.e. `/imagesresources/**`

As far as your eclipse behaviour is concerned, that is relative to your eclipse project. When you deploy your war on tomcat then the resources will not be accessible relative to your eclipse project.

Comment: What is the difference between using <c:url value = "/jsp/index.htm"/> inside src and directly using the imagesresources/contactus.jpg

Comment: @v0ld3m0rt nothing as far as you are not evaluating src values through some context variable. In this case you have hard-coded predefined value /jsp/index.htm so no need to use <c:url> at first place.

Answer (score -1):

In your MVC project AppConfig file -> Override the addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) method. This class (inherits from WebMvcConfigurerAdapter ) and the overrided method's handlers used to serve static resources such as images, js, and css files from specific locations.

Ref this link for a full working example: http://www.technicalkeeda.com/spring-tutorials/spring-4-mvc-static-resource-mapping-example

Comment: You are using OLD XML Configuration based to load the static assets and i shared how to do it using "New ResourceResolvers" for serving the different assets. Be clear on what you need . Ref : https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-static-resources